# Automatic ldap login is possible using django-auth-ldap package?

Tags: django, ldap, single-sign-on, django-auth-ldap

how to achieve **automatic ldap login in django** application?
is it possible by using **django-auth-ldap** package?

Comment: Yes you use ldap for authentication instead of django default authentication. Check the docs https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @NishanPaudel Yes. i was check that docs. but still i am not get any correct solution for it .to get sso or automatic login code.